# Hierarchical axes - plot x-axis labels on top of graph not the bottom

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I've been trying to plot my figure using the code below - my question is how do I have the labels for 0-10 on the x-axis be shown at the top with the 'Level 2' and 'Level 1' labels and not the bottom? (Similar to how the y-axis labels are currently set up) And how do I generally tidy up the labelling of the axes and the axes titles.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.parasite_axes import SubplotHost

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = SubplotHost(fig1, 111)
fig1.add_subplot(ax1)

# First X-axis
ax1.matshow(np.random.rand(10,10))
ax1.xaxis.set_label_text('Sample data x') 
ax1.yaxis.set_label_text("Sample data y")

# Second X-axis
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
offset = 0, 10 # Position of the second axis
new_axisline = ax2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
ax2.axis["top"] = new_axisline(loc="top", axes=ax2, offset=offset)
ax2.axis["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax2.axis["top"].minor_ticks.set_ticksize(0)

ax2.set_xticks([0.0, 0.6, 1.0])
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([0.3, 0.8]))
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(['Level 2', 'Level 1']))
ax2.axis["top"].minor_ticklabels.set(rotation=225)

# Third X-axis
ax3 = ax1.twinx()
offset = -30, 0
new_axisline = ax3.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
ax3.axis["left"] = new_axisline(loc="left", axes=ax3, offset=offset)
ax3.axis["right"].set_visible(False)
ax3.axis["left"].minor_ticks.set_ticksize(0)

ax3.set_yticks([0.0, 0.4, 1.0])
ax3.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
ax3.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([0.2, 0.7]))
ax3.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(['Level 1', 'Level 2']))

fig1.suptitle("My matrix plot")
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]